# eslint-plugin-react breaking, TypeError: Key "plugins": Key "0": Expected an object

Tags: reactjs, eslint, eslint-plugin-react

Eslint breaking when ran while using recommended config from eslint-plugin-react. Attempting to follow the (new: eslint.config.js) section here https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react

```
> Oops! Something went wrong! :(
> 
> ESLint: 8.45.0
> 
> TypeError: Key "plugins": Key "0": Expected an object.
> at Object.validate (/home/kris3579/personalProjects/mal-ranker/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/flat-config-schema.js:315:23)
> at ObjectSchema.validate (/home/kris3579/personalProjects/mal-ranker/node_modules/@humanwhocodes/object-schema/src/object-schema.js:218:35)
> at /home/kris3579/personalProjects/mal-ranker/node_modules/@humanwhocodes/object-schema/src/object-schema.js:171:18
> at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
> at ObjectSchema.merge (/home/kris3579/personalProjects/mal-ranker/node_modules/@humanwhocodes/object-schema/src/object-schema.js:169:24)
> at /home/kris3579/personalProjects/mal-ranker/node_modules/@humanwhocodes/config-array/api.js:916:42
> at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
> at FlatConfigArray.getConfig (/home/kris3579/personalProjects/mal-ranker/node_modules/@humanwhocodes/config-array/api.js:915:39)
> at FlatConfigArray.isFileIgnored (/home/kris3579/personalProjects/mal-ranker/node_modules/@humanwhocodes/config-array/api.js:943:15)
> at /home/kris3579/personalProjects/mal-ranker/node_modules/eslint/lib/eslint/eslint-helpers.js:312:49
>
```

eslint.config.js

```
const js = require('@eslint/js');
const react = require('eslint-plugin-react');

module.exports = [
  js.configs.recommended,
  react.configs.recommended,
  {
    files: ["**/*.js", "**/*.mjs"],
    plugins: {
      react,
    },
  }
];
```

I have tried using the more explicit 'const reactRecommended = require('eslint-plugin-react/configs/recommended');' from the docs, same error.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "placeholder",
  "version": "0.7",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "dotenv": "16.3.1",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.5",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.14.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-table": "^7.8.0",
    "styled-components": "^6.0.4",
    "superagent": "8.0.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint './**/*.js'"
  },
}
```

Also added global.d.ts after seeing a warning 'Could not find a declaration file for module 'eslint-plugin-react', no change to the error

```
declare module 'eslint-plugin-react'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the incompatibility between the classic `.eslintrc` style config and the new Flat config `eslint.config.js`. See [More powerful and configurable plugins](https://eslint.org/blog/2022/08/new-config-system-part-2/#more-powerful-and-configurable-plugins). Most plugin authors haven't migrated their plugins to support the new flat config, so here we are.

See the related issue discussing this problem: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/17355

For now you can change `eslint-plugin-react` yourself, or better open a PR to provide the changes needed.

**eslint.config.js** (same if using CJS)

```js
import react from 'eslint-plugin-react'

// Begin fix
react.configs.recommended.plugins = { react }
react.configs.recommended.languageOptions = {
  parserOptions: react.configs.recommended.parserOptions
}
delete react.configs.recommended.parserOptions
// End fix

export default [
  react.configs.recommended,
  // Now add your own config
  {
    languageOptions: {},
    files: ['**/*.js'],
    plugins: {
      react
    },
    rules: {}
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs plugins need to be in array.

```
const js = require('@eslint/js');
const react = require('eslint-plugin-react');

module.exports = [
  js.configs.recommended,
  react.configs.recommended,
  {
    files: ["**/*.js", "**/*.mjs"],
    plugins: ['react'], // Change this to an array
  }
];
```

Comment: I believe you are following the (legacy: .eslintrc*) section rather than the (new: eslint.config.js) section, still I tried it, same error. ty